# Adding text to datagrid column value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to know if it is possible to add text to a datagrid column value?

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalEuro}" Header="Total €" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Lets say I have the value "240" that I get from a database, now what I need is for it to display as "€ 240". Any advice would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use stringformat

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalEuro, StringFormat=€ {0}}" Header="Total €" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringFormat` to format your binding string and add the text do you need.

Example:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalEuro, StringFormat=€ {0}}" Header="Total €" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Where {0} is your binding. If you need multibinding you can use {1}, {2} etc